# C _Generic and char arrays

Tags: c, generics

I have a generic expression (in a macro):

```
int equal = _Generic(                                                                           
        (actual),                                                                               
        unsigned long:  actual == expected,                                                     
        int:            actual == expected,                                                     
        unsigned char:  actual == expected,                                                     
        char *:         strcmp((char *)actual, (char *)expected) == 0                           
);
```

When I expand it with `actual` being a char[12] it works on some architectures/compilers, but on some I get the error:

```
error: controlling expression type 'char [12]' not compatible with any generic association type
```

How can I handle this without writing a line for every single length of char array?  i.e. `char[0]`, `char[1]`, `char[2]` ...

Forcing the char array to decay into a pointer would do the trick, but I cannot change this macro into a function.  Is there a way to force decay?  I have tried `*&actual`, but it does not result in a `char *`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is due to an ambiguity that was in the C11 text that introduced `_Generic`. It is now resolved by the committee in that it is expected that array to pointer conversion is performed to determine the matching type.

For the time being you can work around this by using your `actual` in an expression that does this conversion. I'd suggest

```
bool equal = _Generic(                                                                           
        (actual)+0,                                                                               
        default:  actual == expected,                                                     
        char *:         strcmp((char *)actual, (char *)expected) == 0                           
);
```

BTW, your code is not completely type save, because it doesn't check the type of `expected`. I'd try to have a second `_Generic` that ensures that.

Comment: note: 1st char* cast not needed,  2:maybe type safe not type save

Comment: @chux, in fact it is, unfortunately, at least if you want to plug this code into a macro that is valid for all the cases. All branches of a `_Generic` must be valid. So if the expression is met with an integer type, the call to `strcmp` must still be valid, otherwise the compiler will wine.

Comment: Yes, it's not type safe on the second argument.  I've documented with a `FIXME:`.

Comment: My comment was not on the branch, but on the _cast_.  `strcmp(actual,..` is suffcient without the cast.  No need to cast `actual` as part of the `strcmp()` call.  The first cast is not needed,

Comment: @chux, mine was also on the cast. Try to compile the `_Generic` expression with `-Wall` by feeding in two integers as actual and expected. Without cast the compiler would still see the branch `strcmp(actual, expected) == 0` even if it is not evaluated. And it would complain about it.

Comment: Yes fair enoguh.